# Collates the number of depots that don't have manifests and trunk headers

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

Trying to do a work project that collates the number of depots that don't have manifests and trunk headers.

- Column A: Depot Numbers
- Column B: No Manifest record (i.e if Colum B 2 - 200 contains "value x" then means no manifest)
- Column C: Same as column B but for Trunk Headers instead of Manifests
- Column D: List of Depot numbers in numerical order (2 - 200)
- Column E: Collated total of "no manifests" from column B "cells 2 - 200" if column A collates with the relevant Depot Number (i.e Column D4 will be Depot 3 and E4 will show the total number of Depot 3's that don't have manifests collated from Column A and B (column A is depot number & column B is no manifest))
- Column F: Same as Column E but for No Trunk Header instead of No Manifest.

Can someone please assist as I'm not sure if I need `REGEXMATCH` or something else.

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet and include an example of desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T16jwFg6dTLEHQcmuiNrlpBiBWQ21j7A_AOnmXmp05E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: There is a link to the spreadsheet, I decided to change it a little bit. 

Basically trying to get Colum D and E to display the total count for each depot from Column A and B.

Needs to search for a "Text Value" then increase the count in Column D and E that corresponds to the given Depot number

Comment: which means if UKD002 if found in A2:A200 it needs to increase the corresponding value in Column D by 1 for UKD002 (if that makes sense?)

Comment: nope, not a close, pls provide some more details. it's just not clear what's the logic nor how should the final result look like. do you want to count unique occurrences from column A if found in column C ??

Comment: If unique occurence is found in Column A in needs to increase the count for that desired occurence in Column D.

If the unique occurence appears in Column B it needs to increase the count for that desired occurence in Column E.

does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C$2:$C, QUERY({A2:A}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''"), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SB9HuUTKo0M-BEIgIJP44wbMkqc3QodZPzN7OBvgfRo/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: Thank you for your formula, although I have a question as I pasted this formula in Cell D2 and it returns a #REF! error saying data in the cell would be replaced if formula was placed in that cell.

Error
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in D3.

Comment: yeah. delete stuff in D3 onwards to be able this formula to roll out